# Form inputs not lining up using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a sample jsFiddle here, with the html copied straight from my web page.  I have included the css for bootstrap 4 which i have compiled using sass, along with the rest of my css.

Now from what i can see, this should all line up fine, and on all sizes it does, until you get to a small display.  Then for some reason the input boxes and buttons seem to go all the way to the edge, but the rest of the content (labels, headers, p text, tabs etc) seem to stay within the bounds of the tab-content box.

Here is the link to the jsFiddle example

https://jsfiddle.net/Gillardo/y3Lr9sbf/1/

Why is this?  Have i laid something out incorrectly, or is it just a bug with bootstrap 4 currently?  I am asking here because if i go to the bs4 examples, it lays out correctly, which you can find here, and i cannot tell what i have done differently http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#using-the-grid

An example of how my form is created, using form-group is like so

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 form-control-label">Label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7">
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" disabled="disabled">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There seems to be something missing. In the demo page (getbootstrap.com) they have source maps enabled and the `_grid-framework.scss` file provides some padding for the `col-*` elements. This is what makes them line up. Maybe you should check your compile step.

Answer (score 0):

Class `.tab-content` is set with `0` padding, if you want some change the following:

```
.nav-pills+.tab-content {
    border: 0;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
    padding-left: 0; // <-- change
    padding-right: 0; // <-- change
}
```

Comment: Removing ```padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0``` doesnt sort the problem. Because the inputs now dont go all the way to the edge, but all the other content is now pushed in...

Comment: I meant change them to e.g. `padding-left: 15px`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer, modify .row class to remove negative margins:

```
.row{
 margin-left: 0 !important;
 margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I thought this was a silly answer, but it actually works.  in that case, why do rows add negative margins in the first place?